# Add www to non-www address with ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl

I would like all traffic without the www, including https, to be redirected to the respective url with the www.

So http://example.com -> http://www.example.com, https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

There's plenty of info online about forcing ssl, which I do not want to do, and forcing www, but only for http. Just adding an s and changing the listen 80 -> listen 443 breaks the http sites. Here's my config so far:

```
  server {
    listen  80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
      rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$1  permanent;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root   /opt/example;
    index  index.html;

    <locations stuff>
  }

  server {
    listen  443;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /opt/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /opt/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    location / {
      rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.example.com/$1  permanent;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen  443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root   /opt/example;

    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /opt/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /opt/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    <locations stuff>
  }
```

Comment: Adding an `s` where?  Breaks the http sites how?

Comment: Sorry adding an s after http in the rewrite rule. Basically it does not respond to http requests.

Answer (score 3):

This is a stripped down version of my own config, which I think does what you want:

```
server {
    listen 80  default;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name *.example.com;

    if ($host = example.com) {
        rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    }

    root   /opt/example;

    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /opt/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /opt/nginx/ssl/server.key;
}
```

Comment: i was looking for this way of doing it thanks, i like it because you only use one server block